# Renaming files in directory based on filename using R

Tags: r, file-rename

I have a dataframe (FilesDf) containing each filename and the substitution I need to make to it (FilesDf$FileTags).

```
FileName                  Filename          FileTags
H:/name/+Sm,Jon.docx      +Sm,Jon.docx      RR UB AF-
H:/name/+Suth,Jane.docx   +Suth,Jane.docx   AF-
H:/name/+Dunn,Robert.docx +Dunn,Robert.docx RR LL-
```

For each of the filenames in this folder, I need to affix the FileTags as a prefix. The filenames need to look like this:

```
RR UB AF-Sm,Jon.docx      
AF-Suth,Jane.docx   
RR LL-Dunn,Robert.docx
```

My attempt:

```
Filepath <- "H:/name/"
files <- list.files(Filepath,pattern = "*.doc",full.names = T) 

nrow<-nrow(FilesDf)

for(i in nrow){
sapply(files,FUN=function(eachPath){ 
   file.rename(from=eachPath,to= sub(pattern="\\+", 
   FilesDf$FileTags[i],eachPath))
})
}
```

But this results in all the files having the same prefix rather than having the prefix that corresponds correctly to the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do things in phases, partly to make sure it's working correctly (testing), partly because it's easy to maintain/extend.

```
FilesDf$FileName2 <- file.path(dirname(FilesDf$FileName),
                               gsub("\\+", "", paste0(FilesDf$FileTags, FilesDf$Filename)))
FilesDf
#                    FileName          Filename  FileTags                      FileName2
# 1      H:/name/+Sm,Jon.docx      +Sm,Jon.docx RR UB AF-   H:/name/RR UB AF-Sm,Jon.docx
# 2   H:/name/+Suth,Jane.docx   +Suth,Jane.docx       AF-      H:/name/AF-Suth,Jane.docx
# 3 H:/name/+Dunn,Robert.docx +Dunn,Robert.docx    RR LL- H:/name/RR LL-Dunn,Robert.docx
```

If the new names (`$FileName2`) look good, then

```
ign <- mapply(file.rename, FilesDf$FileName, FilesDf$FileName2)
```

should work.

*(I was initially distracted by `$FileName` vs `$Filename`, and missed the second ...)*

---

Data:

```
FilesDf <- structure(list(FileName = c("H:/name/+Sm,Jon.docx", "H:/name/+Suth,Jane.docx", 
"H:/name/+Dunn,Robert.docx"), Filename = c("+Sm,Jon.docx", "+Suth,Jane.docx", 
"+Dunn,Robert.docx"), FileTags = c("RR UB AF-", "AF-", "RR LL-"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But after running the file.rename, I keep getting the error:
Error in (function (from, to)  : invalid 'from' argument

Comment: Your first column are `factor`s, not `character`s. Change the first argument to `dirname(as.character(FilesDf$FileName))`.